# Getting x coordinate from sns.kdeplot

Tags: python, statistics, data-visualization, data-science, cdf

Question 1. I am trying to find a kde plot for my data

I am trying to use the following commands

> import seaborn as sns
>
> ax = sns.kdeplot(students,cumulative = True)

This gives the correct kde plot , but I cannot get the CDF x-coordinate for 0.8 , 0.9 or any other value. What is going wrong here?

Question 2. Using statmodels - https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.nonparametric.kde.KDEUnivariate.html

The above sit mentions cdf as -  `Returns the cumulative distribution function evaluated at the support.`

Can you please tell me what does `support` refer to here?

Comment: You might want to split these into two separate questions. I can answer the latter question though. The support is (more or less) defined as the part of the domain of a function whose elements map to a nonzero value, i.e. f(x) != 0 for every x in the support of f.